# Installing Wordpress in Apache

Tags: apache-http-server, wordpress, hosting, web-hosting

So, I've installed Wordpress in Apache and have it working, i.e. I can browse to it on my hosting server via localhost and it displays my blog, all good and well. But when (anyone) browses to it from outside my network, i.e. via my WAN IP (nat'ed to my Server) all the formatting goes haywire, colours, text everywhere, images not appearing etc. I just don't get it, at first I thought browser, but I've tried multiple all with the same results. Any ideas?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People browsing from the outside are likely using a different URL (domain name or IP address) than you are when you are "inside". Wordpress only installed to the "inside" URL. You will need to migrate Wordpress to the outside URL, which is not exactly a trivial process but can be done. You can actually set the admin and public sites to work on different URL's if you want to access Admin only from the "inside".

Here is the official guide on moving / changing domain:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_to_a_New_Server

Comment: Do you know of any good resources/guides for the migration process Josh?

Comment: Updated my answer - see above.